# Conditional Compilation #ifdef

Tags: c, macros, conditional-compilation

I am trying to understand the `#ifdef` macros. Sample code below.

```
getval(int val)
{
  if(val==0) {
    #ifndef PKT
    #define PKT
    #endif
  }
}
main() {
getval(0);
#ifdef PKT
printf("Packet\n");
#endif
}
```

I get output `Packet` even when I pass `1` to `getval`. Why am I getting output when `PKT` is not defined when `val=1` ? Thanks.

Comment: Because the define is not executed at run-time.

Comment: This answer would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349387/scope-of-macros-in-c/17349448

Answer (score 2):

The `#` directives are compile time and not run time. So it doesn't matter what you pass. If the macro `PKT` is defined then "Packet" is printed, else not.

If you are running `gcc` you can do `gcc -E myfile.c` and check the result after preprocessing.

If you remove the bunch of preprocessor directives from your `getval` function, then the "Packet" will not be printed, because in that case `PKT` is not defined, and therefore the `#ifdef PKT` is false and the `printf` does not reach the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

That part where you `#define PKT` is evaluated by the preprocessor before the actual compilation, not during programm execution. Therefore, it is not subject to the condition `if(val==0)`.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` and `#ifdef` are evaluated at compile time (actually even before compilation). They are evaluated on a text file, independently of the C code which is below. Therefore in

```
if(val==0) {
   #ifndef PKT
   #define PKT
   #endif
}
```

The `#define` is always done. Otherwise said, your code is equivalent to the same code where the define are outside a function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: What is the use of `#ifndef` directive then. How can I achieve my intention to conditionally print `Packet` only if `PKT` is defined.

Comment: You are already conditionally printing if PKT is defined. Only the fact that PKT is defined is computed by **reading linearly the source file** as opposed to **executing** it. Could you explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I am just trying to print conditionally using if directives.

Comment: Then use normal ``if`` instead of compile time ``ifdef`` !

Answer (score 1):

This code could be used instead:

```
#define val 0

#if val==0
  #ifndef PKT
    #define PKT
  #endif
#endif //val == 0

int main()
{
#ifdef PKT 
    printf("Packet\n");
#endif
}
```

However, note that you've to define val before compilation.

Or, you could use enum:

```
typedef enum {PKT, NO_PKT} Packet;
Packet p;

getval(int val)
{
    if (val == 0)
    p = PKT;
    else
    p = NO_PKT;
}

int main()
{
   getval(1);
   if (p == PKT)
        printf("Packet\n");
}
```